# Inclusion Map $i : A \to X $ i(a) =a is continous for all a $a\in A$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

While trying my assignment questions on Topology I am struck on the following assignment problem .

> Let $(A, T_A) $ be a subspace of topological space (X,T). Prove that inclusion Map $i : A \to X $ i(a) =a is continuous for all a $a\in A$.

Well, The definition of continuity  is defined for open set and not for any element as given in the question. So, I am confused on how to prove continuos as defining open set by the help of element has onlly one meaning( in my opinion) that I took an open set A' whose element is a' ( There could be many open sets , I chose any 1) , now I have to prove that $i^{-1} A' \in A'$ but by i(a)=a , as i is 1-1 and for each a there exists a st i(a) =a , in my case there exists an a' st i(a') =a' and a' will belong to A'. So, for each A'$\subseteq X$, there exists an A'$\subseteq X$  and hence i is continuous.

this was my thinking. kindly tell what is my mistake in case i am wrong .

Comment: Should it be phrased like this?  "The inclusion map $i : A \to X$ is continuous, where $i$ is defined by $i(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like what you should prove is that, for every open set $O\in T$, its preimage $i^{-1}(O)\in T_A$.

This is almost trivial.

> Let $O\in T$. Then $i^{-1}(O)=O\cap A$. Because $O$ is open in $X$, by the definition of subspace topology, we know $i^{-1}(O)$ is open in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take an open subset O of X (i.e. a set from T)  you can disjointly devide it into $O\cap A$ and $O\cap A^c$. Then the latter part doesn't have a preimage, thus $i^{-1}(O\cap A^c)$ equals the empty set. Since $O\cap A$ is an open set (by definition of the subspace topology), and $i^{-1}(O\cap A)=O\cap A$, you know that $i^{-1}(O)=\emptyset\cup (O\cap A)$ is an open set.